# Работать сидя на стуле – обособление и синтаксический разбор

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот, дополнение, обстоятельство

Рассмотрим оборот: ***работать () сидя на стуле.***

Интересно, что и постановка запятой, и синтаксическая роль оборота определяются по контексту.
Я приведу пример с уже сделанным разбором, но хотелось бы услышать **ваше мнение о правильности** решенной задачи.

При решении использованы определения терминов, взятые из учебника для вузов:  Кустова Г.И Синтаксис современного русского языка, стр. 81
[https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

(1)  *Я пересяду с кресла на стул. **Мне удобнее рабОтать, сидя на стУле**.*
(Мне удобнее работать, если я сижу на стуле,  а не на кресле).

В этом случае мы **обособляем**  деепричастный оборот в качестве аналога придаточного предложения.  При разборе обособленная конструкция подчеркивается как единый член предложения. Это обстоятельство **условия**, но не обстоятельство образа действия.

Но если разбирать оборот **отдельно** или если разбирать придаточное предложение, то падежная форма «на стуле» будет **дополнением**: сидя (на чем?) на стуле;   сижу (не чем?) на стуле, а не на кресле. В этом случае объект дополняет действие, выраженное глагольными формами (значение взаимодействия с объектом).

(2)  ***Теперь я никуда не Езжу, работаю сидя на стУле.***

В этом предложении оборот  **не обособляется**. Значение переносное: неподвижно, не двигаясь, не перемещаясь, сидя не стуле. Теперь  это качественная характеристика действия: работаю  (как?) сидя на стуле.  Деепричастный оборот  в переносном значении является **устойчивым сочетанием** и разбирается как единый член предложения – обстоятельство **образа действия**.

В приведенном решении не все утверждения могут считаться однозначно правильными. Пожалуйста,  скажите, **с чем вы не согласны**, и кратко объясните **причину**.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я могу судить, любой оборот, стоящий под ударением, не обособляется, если только это не фигуральный прием сравнение. Вот несколько примеров из Розенталя:

Писал он обычно наклонив голову. (говорящий произносит предложение с целью охарактеризовать то, как «он» писал)
Яков сидел опустив ноги. (говорящий произносит предложение с целью охарактеризовать то, как сидел Яков)

Предложение: «Мне удобнее рабОтать сидя на стУле.» — произносится для того, что бы сообщить об удобном способе работы. Крайне трудно придумать контекст, при котором после слова «работать» ставилась бы запятая.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий**

**Спасибо вам за ответ** и за внимание к моему вопросу, у меня будут такие замечания.

1. Вы говорите:  «Насколько я могу судить, любой оборот, стоящий под ударением, не обособляется.  А что это значит – **ударная позиция для оборота**? Я примерно догадываюсь,  что вы имеете в виду, но хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение.
2. Примеры, которые вы приводите,  Розенталь **объясняет так**: оборот не обособляется, если тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания (примечание  в конце пункта 4).  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113

Про ударение здесь не говорится ничего. В то же время в п.6 есть пример обособления деепричастия в аналогичной позиции: *Казаки разъехались, **не договорившись**.*

3. Примеры лучше не придумывать,  а  **брать из Нацкорпуса.** Там  очень много примеров с обособлением, например: *Фекла Парамоновна крепко спалА, **сидя на стУле**.* https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&

Можно придумать такой пример: *Он привык рабОтать,  **сидя на стУле.*** Что мне может помешать произнести эту фразу **с двумя ударениями**. Это авторский выбор.

Можно обратить внимание на то, что часто не обособляются обороты со значением **позы** (неклонив голову, опустив ноги), но здесь говорится о частях тела, а стул — это отдельный предмет.

4. **А делается он так.** В п. 6. Розенталь говорит, что деепричастие обособляется, если сохраняет значение глагольности и указывает на **время действия, его причину, условие** и т. д. (но не на образ действия): ***Уходя**, гасите свет*: (когда гаси́те?); *Он поправил меня, **смеясь***. *Потом шаги их затихли, **удаляясь.**  С усмешкой сказал он, **интригуя**.*

Сравнить: Поезд шёл **не останавливаясь** — ‘безостановочно’, значение образа действия.

Но и здесь возможен **авторский выбор:** Он кивнул и взлетел через пролет. *Дальше бежал, **не останавливаясь**.* Мокрые джинсы липли к ногам. [Мариам Петросян. Дом, в котором... (2009)]  Значение: бежал и при этом не останавливался.

В моем же примере присутствует значение **условия, но не образа действия**.

Comment: С каждым разом всё понятнее и понятнее эта тема. Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо вам за оценку!

Answer (score 0):

Сразу скажу, что я не читал об этом нигде, кроме очень очень очень очень плохих статей. Все, что написано, является результатом моих размышлений, находящихся на зачаточном уровне.
Вот четыре примера разных смысловых ударений у одного и того же предложения: «Я сегодня поеду на рынок.»

— Кто сегодня будет затариваться едой?
— Я сегодня поеду на рынок. (ударение падает на «Я». Цель произношения предложения — сообщить автора действия «затариваться».)

— Когда ты купишь овощей?
— Я сегодня поеду на рынок. (ударение падает на «сегодня». Цель произношения предложения — сообщить время покупки овощей.)

— Если будешь идти на рынок, то зайди ко мне.
— Я сегодня поеду на рынок. (ударение падает на «поеду». Цель произношения предложения — сообщить способ передвижения.)

— Куда ты сегодня собрался?
— Я сегодня поеду на рынок. (ударение падает на «рынок». Цель произношения предложения — сообщить пункт назначения.)

Все статьи, в которых пишут на эту тему, объединяет одно заблуждение — зависимость ударения от интонации(я предпочитаю термин «характер произношения», так как выделять слова можно множеством способов: замедлением речи, паузами до и после слова и тд). В соответствующих ситуациях вы можете произнести предложения, расположенные выше, с одинаковым характером произношения — и люди вас поймут, не исходя из характера произношения, а из контекста.

Смысловое ударение не может падать на часть оборота, так как оборот — неделимая синтаксическая единица.

Далее, я буду объяснять ударение на примерах связанных с обсуждаемой темой. Возьмем предложение: «Он шел по улице прихрамывая.»

Каждый раз, выходя утром на улицу, я вижу человека, который совершает пробежку, но на этот раз он идет и прихрамывает. Вспоминая этот случай, я скажу: «Он шел по улице, прихрамывая». Ударение на «шел». Важно то, что он шел, а не бежал.

Я не видел своего друга Никиту пару дней. Я вижу, как он идет по улице и прихрамывает. Прихрамывание примечательно для меня, так как заставляет задуматься о том, что с ним случилось. Вспоминая это, я скажу: «Он шел по улице прихрамывая.» Ударение на «прихрамывая». Важно то, что он идет прихрамывая.

Далее, примеры, в которых вы меня уличили.

— Собрание еще продолжается?
— Казаки разъехались, не договорившись.(ударение на «разъехались»)

— Чем все закончилось?
— Казаки разъехались не договорившись.(ударение на «не договорившись»)

Я зашел спросить совета, но Фекла Парамоновна крепко спала, сидя на стуле.
Предо мной предстала умиляющая картина: Фекла Парамоновна крепко спала сидя на стуле.

Comment: Пунктуация — не игра на пианино, а базовый инструмент коммуникации. Пунктуация не должна и не занимается отражением тонких или  не значимых для смысла интонационных отличий. В базовых принципах: смысловые отличия, синтаксическое членение, характер произношения — приоритет отдается первым двум пунктам. Пунктуация отражает только какие-то базовые, грубые, отчетливые, смыслозначимые,  элементы произношения.

Comment: Возьмем любое предложение, например: «Отлично экипированные для похода, ребята не боялись  природы.». Мы всегда ставим запятую после слова «поход», но произносить можем как угодно.
Можно делать паузу после слова «поход», а можно после слова «ребята».

Что касается статьи. Во первых, здесь почти не говорится о постановке знаков препинания, кроме пары реплик о том, что при короткой паузе запятая не ставится, при более длинной — ставится.

Comment: Во вторых, здесь вводится какой-то свой термин для ударения, который не связан с логическим ударением из всех остальных статей, что я читал. Возможно, это статьи из некого раздела лингвистики, который изучает тонкие интонационные отличия. Все это имеет слабое отношение к пунктуации, и мне этот раздел не интересен.

Comment: Давайте так. Лично я потратила много времени, чтобы объяснить ваши предложения, но у меня получился объемный материал. Ваш вопрос тоже выпадает из этой темы. Я предлагаю вам оформить этот материал как отдельный вопрос, тогда я помещу там свой ответ. Я пишу ответы не лично для вас, но и для других участников или гостей форума, которые сюда заходят. Я полагаю, что им это может быть интересно. Вы могли бы назвать тему так: «О логическом выделении нужных слов в предложении, в том числе при обособлении». . Если у вас нет желания это делать, то я могу сама задать  вопрос. Ответьте мне, пожалуйста.

Comment: Отлично экипированные для похода, ребята не боялись природы. Вы можете ставить ударение на любом слове оборота, но должны  его обязательно поставить  хотя бы где-то при обособлении. А если нет обособления, то ударение переходит на сущ. "ребята". Думаю, разница вам понятна. Вы мыслите в пределах частных деталей, а пунктуация обозначает обобщенные формы.

Comment: Мне все кристально ясно в этом вопросе. Я не могу найти во всей классической литературе пример, который бы противоречил моим представления . Но, пожалуйста. Правда, я не очень понимаю, что мне следует спросить. Лучше вы задайте вопрос, приведите примеры, а я поучаствую в обсуждении.

Comment: Если хотите, что бы я задал вопрос, то я могу задать вопрос.

Comment: Пожалуйста, если вам не трудно