# Не могли бы вы пояснить: что такое логическое ударение и каковы особенности обособления оборотов, находящихся под логическим ударением?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Не могли бы вы пояснить: что такое логическое ударение и каковы особенности обособления оборотов, находящихся под логическим ударением?

Answer (score 3):

**1. Введение в тему**

Существует ли  связь между ударением и интонацией в общем случае? Разумеется, да.
Дело в том, что **ударение** – это и есть интонация, то есть ее основной элемент.

Вот обычное определение: **Интона́ция** (лат. intonō «громко произношу») — совокупность **просодических** характеристик предложения: тона (мелодики речи), громкости, темпа речи и её отдельных отрезков, ритмики, особенностей фонации.

Как мы видим, здесь много факторов, поэтому в интонационной модели  нужно выбрать самые важные и работать уже с ними. В  качестве основных факторов выбирается **тоническое ударение и паузы.**

**Примечания.**

**Просодический** –  греч.prosodikos –  касающийся ударения). Относящийся к явлениям высоты тона, длительности, силы звука и т. п.

**Ударение в слове.** Слог, который произносится с большей силой и длительностью, называется ударным слогом. Гласный звук ударного слога называется ударным гласным.

**Тоническое ударение** – это дополнительное изменение высоты звука  ударного слога (его частотной характеристики.

**Логическое (смысловое) ударение** – это обычно (1) смещенное тоническое ударение или (2) его дополнительное  силовое выделение.

Если при нейтральной интонации ударение падает **на конец фонетической фразы,** то логического выделения слова нет, а **смещение** ударения на другие слова мы воспринимаем как их **логическое выделение.**

**О логическом  ударении**

Логическое ударение – это средство **смыслового** выделения какой-либо значимой единицы высказывания. Накладываясь на обязательное словесное ударение, логическое ударение обычно **усиливает фонетические характеристики** слова, подчёркивая информацию, новую или спорную для одного из собеседников. Например, во фразе «Твоя сестра пришла» логическое ударение может выделить любое из трёх слов. Это достигается  средствами графики (выделяющие шрифты), лексики (слова «именно», «как раз» и т. п.), синтаксиса (порядок слов, выделительные обороты).
[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/104283/Логическое](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/104283/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5)

Можно также посмотреть:  https://izamorfix.ru/rus/sint_punkt/logicheskoe_udarenie.html

Таким образом, надо точно понимать значение **каждого термина,** который мы употребляем.

**Приложение.** Интонационная модель предложения [https://cloud.mail.ru/home/Конспект%20%20статьи%20из%20Интернета.docx?weblink=qrEC/srex719a8](https://cloud.mail.ru/home/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%20%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0.docx?weblink=qrEC/srex719a8)

2. Примеры разного произношения для предложения: ***Я сегодня поеду на рынок.***

2.1. Нейтральная интонация. Предложение состоит из двух фонетических фраз,  тоническое ударение падает на конец каждой фразы, логического выделения нет, например в начале текста:   ***Я сегОдня // поеду на рЫнок.***  Каждая поездка для меня – это настоящее испытание.

2.2. Но в диалоге часто приходится **логически выделять** нужное слово.

Если нужное слово **смещено** относительно с конца фразы, то требуется незначительное усиление голоса (смещение + усиление).

Если же оно стоит **в конце фразы**, то на него уже падает тоническое ударение. Тогда  для его выделения используется только **сила** голоса.

Именно поэтому логическое выделение слова в конце фразы вообще не очень удобно, в то время как смещением можно добиться нужного **эффекта и без особых усилий.**

**Кто** сегодня будет затариваться едой? —  **Я** сегодня // поеду на рынок.

**Когда** ты купишь овощей? — Я **сегОдня** //поеду на рынок

Если будешь **идти** на рынок, то зайди ко мне.— Я сегодня // поЕду на рынок.

Куда ты сегодня собрался? — Я сегодня // поеду **на рЫнок**.

3. **Логическое ударение и обособление** (парные варианты с обособлением и без обособления)

3.1. В приведенных примерах  даются парные варианты с разной пунктуацией.  Во всех случаях **тоническое ударение** в конце каждой  фразы присутствует.

Но при обособлении делается **подчеркнутая пауза**, которая и создает **эффект выделени**я слова в конц**е первой фразы, тогда **тоническое ударение** воспринимается как** логическое выделение.

При отсутствии обособления **пауза произносительная**, поэтому эффект выделения отсутствует, это **нейтральная** интонация. **Силовое** выделение при обособлении  **не требуется,** что весьма удобно.

**3.2. Пример парного варианта**

(1)  ***Он шел по улице //  прихрамывая.***

В предложении две фразы. При отсутствии обособления мы имеем **нейтральную интонацию** с тоническим ударением в конце каждой фразы. Здесь качественная характеристика походки, значение обстоятельства образа действия. Логическое выделение  не требуется,  нейтральная интонация нас вполне устраивает

(2) А если поставить запятую? ***Он шЕл по улице, прихрАмывая.***

При обособлении  пауза   создает эффект выделения.  Мы можем поставить тоническое ударение на конец фразы, выделив слово «на улице», но нам удобнее сместить тоническое ударение  на слово «шёл», чтобы выделить его.

**3.3. Другие парные варианты**

В этих примерах **смещения ударения  нет**: мы  выделяем или не выделяем слово в конце первой фразы.

При обособлении это делается с помощью подчеркнутой паузы, вследствие чего  тоническое  ударение воспринимается как ударение логическое.

(1)  «**Чем** все закончилось?» — «Казаки разъехались // **не договорИвшись**». «Собрание еще продолжается?» — «Казаки **разъЕхались**, не договорИвшись.

(2) Предо мной предстала умиляющая **картина**: Фекла Парамоновна крепко **спала // сидя на стуле.**  Я зашел спросить совета, но Фекла Парамоновна крепко **спалА**, сидя на стУле.

В ответе использованы примеры из ответа на вопрос [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463934/Работать-сидя-на-стуле-обособление-и-синтаксический-разбор/463942?noredirect=1#comment481147_463942](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463934/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80/463942?noredirect=1#comment481147_463942)

Comment: Во превых, термин «логическое» ударение. Совершенно непонятно, при чем здесь какое-либо значение слова «логика». Наиболее распространенное значение слова «логика» — это связь между выводом и имеющийся информацией, а формальная логика — это обуславливание выводов языком.  Как это связанно с данным ударением? Это ярчайший пример, как филологи могут заблудится в трех соснах, при простом подборе слова для термина.

Comment: Во вторых, термин «логическое ударение» произошел от термина «ударение» на основании схожих характеристик: Там буквы — здесь слова, там выделяется буква — здесь слово. Не факт, что интонация является схожей характеристика для этого, так же как не факт, что «ударение» по всем характеристикам соотносится с словом «ударять».

Comment: В третьих. Тот факт, что последующие предложения можно произнести с абсолютно одинаковым характером произношения, а смысл будет понятен, как и логическое ударение определено, — говорит о том, что нет прямой связи между интонацией и логическим ударением. 
«Кто сегодня будет затариваться едой?»  — «Я сегодня поеду на рынок.» (ударение падает на «Я»)
«Когда ты купишь овощей?» — «Я сегодня поеду на рынок.» (ударение падает на «сегодня»)
Это — ударение контекстом! Нам вообще не нужна знать интонацию дабы понимать смысл или определять ударение.

Comment: Какой-то низкопробный (не обременённый интеллектом) троллинг. А если по существу, то сразу бросается в глаза систематическая ошибка: слова *во-первых, во-вторых, в-третьих* пишутся через дефис.

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили меня. Но, может быть, вы приведете свои аргументы в пользу того, что логическое ударение все же определяется интонацией? Так сказать, по существу.

Comment: Это что, так сложно понять, что ударение не связано напрямую с интонацией?  Вы можете произнести предложение множеством способов , но ударение от этого не изменится.

Comment: @Jim Korbett,полностью согласен с комментарием  grizzly. Вы ведь не только задаете вопросы, вы еще и отвечаете на них. Значит, у вас есть определенные познания в русском. Вместо того, чтобы начинать спорить, обвинять филологов, лингвистов в ошибках, удосужились бы найти информацию и узнать,почему логическое ударение именно так называется. Прошу. [Логическое ударение](https://lektsii.org/11-57789.html)

Comment: @Sharon А как отличить синтагму от фонетической фразы? Типа, если длинная пауза, то фраза, а если короткая — синтагма?

Comment: Максим, почитайте, пожалуйста ,вот эту тему https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474316/О-логических-тонических-и-прочих-ударениях-при-постановке-знаков-препинания/474320#comment507065_474320  Если останутся вопросы, тогда напишите мне, а то я буду повторяться. Там дано определение этих терминов.