# О логических, тонических и прочих ударениях при постановке знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация, орфоэпия

На форуме при выборе **знаков препинания** часто говорится о расстановке **ударений** в предложении, но не всегда понятно, о каком ударении идет речь.

Answer (score 3):

**Краткая информация об ударениях**

В русском языке **словесное** ударение определяется по силе и длительности звучания ударного гласного.

Существует еще **тоническое ударение**  —  повышение или понижение тона ударного гласного в предложении. Тоническую природу имеет  **фразовое и тактовое** ударение. (Термин «тактовое ударение» имеет частный характер, обычно при анализе знаков препинания говорят о фразовом/тоническом ударении.)

**Фраза**  —  это самая крупная фонетическая единица. К примеру, простое предложение состоит из двух фраз с повышением и понижением тона, а сложное предложение может включать несколько фраз. Каждая фраза имеет только **одно** фразовое (тоническое) ударение. (Так формируется сама фраза.)
Фразы разделяются паузами, обычно ударение делается в конце фразы.

**Синтагма** — часть фразы, ее называют также **тактом** (такт — это скорее музыкальный термин). Синтагмы разделяются в речи небольшими (произносительными) паузами. По сути это деление предложения на **структурно-смысловые** фонетические отрезки.

**Примечание**. В последнем такте фразы фразовое ударение совпадает с тактовым. В общем случае тактовое ударение **слабее** фразового, поэтому **фразовое ударение более значимое,** именно о нем обычно идет речь при анализе предложения.

**Логическим ударением** мы выделяем значимое (ключевое) слово. Это ударение может быть тоническим или силовым. Логическое ударение возможно в том случае,  если ударение **смещается** с конца фразы на другое слово (тогда фразовое ударение становится логическим).

Выделение слова возможно при постановке его **в ударную позицию** (например, в конец слова). Также такой эффект достигается при **инверсии** слов.

В предложении **с ровной интонацией** есть фразовые ударения, но  логических ударений там нет. В других случаях фразовое ударение **становится** логическим (приобретает выделительное значение).

**Зачем все это нужно?**

Это нужно для построения **правильной структуры** предложения и выбора **порядка слов** в нем (носители все делают по интуиции), важно это и при  постановке **знаков препинания**.

**Примечание.** В ответе приведен материал справочного характера, а всю терминологию можно проверить в Интернете. Я отвечу только на конструктивные вопросы (уточнение или улучшение моего ответа) **по терминологии.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.**

К сожалению, мне пришлось убрать разбор практического примера, так как такая задача вообще не ставилась в вопросе. Я считаю, что сообщила достаточно информации, чтобы можно было  **понять значение терминов**. Надеюсь, что ответ поможет **самостоятельно** разобраться в теме всем интересующимся.

И еще раз повторю, что вся информация по ударениям и терминам **есть в Интернете,** я же просто привела ее в ответе в качестве **справки**.

Answer (score 1):

**Не совсем понятно, о каком ударении идёт речь?**

Может быть потому, что вы сами использовали термин ‟ударение” во многих последних ответах. Сначала вы писали ‟логическое ударение”, потом я отчётливо объяснил, что это такое, после чего вы стали писать просто ‟ударение”. (Александр сделал так же, о чём сам сказал напрямую.) Можно сказать, что я описал не логическое, а какое-то другое ударение, но вы же перестали писать ‟логическое”, а на этом основании можно сделать вывод, что вы сами не понимаете, что там по общепринятой терминологии и какое это ударение, о котором вы писали. Так какое ударение вы имели в виду в последних 50 ответах с этим термином, когда использовали просто термин ‟ударение”: логическое, тоническое, тактовое, синтагматическое или другое?

Вы даже в этом ответе использовали термин ударение – ‟Логическое ударение возможно в том случае, если ударение смещается с конца фразы на другое слово”; какое ударение смещается: фразовое или тактовое?

**А как это определить?**

Вы написали следующее предложение и сказали, что это фразовые ударения: ‟Мы идем в шкОлу, // где нам предстоит получить новые знания / и встретить старых друзЕй”. То есть это фразовые ударения. Хорошо, а как определить фразовое ударение? По каким таким характеристикам? Как вы поняли, что ударение не на ‟идём” или не на ‟старых”?

И ещё кое-что, Александр сказал, что имел ввиду тактовое ударение под термином ‟ударение”, а вы, оказывается, имели ввиду фразовое ударение. Получается, что вы друг другу ставили плюсы, но говорили о разных ударениях. И другие пользователи называли это тактовое ударение.

**А какое то ударение?**

Если это не соответствует общепринятой терминологии, то напишите, какое это ударение.

Вот текст из того вопроса:

Будем считать логическим ударением ударение в предложениях:

> Трампа забанила ЧАСТНАЯ компания. (Ударение на ‟частная”.)
> Это ЖЕНСКИЙ туалет. (Когда мужчина находится в женском туалете и кто-то возмущён. Ударение на ‟женский”.)

То есть когда человек имеет некие специфические причины выделить некое слово, когда это слово произносится более громко и ударная гласная этого слова произносится более затянуто. Отмечу, что такое ударение является крайне редким в речи, в большинстве предложений вообще нет такого ударения. Если взять какое-нибудь предложение, например: ‟Вася пошёл в магазин”, то здесь нет логического ударения – нет каких-то специфических причин выделить какое-то слово, никакое слово не произносится более громко, никакая ударная гласная не тянется.

**И ещё.**

И расставьте ещё фазовые ударения в следующих предложениях, чтобы было яснее:

> Все однородные произносятся с одинаковой интонацией.
>
> Купи лук, картошку, капусту
>
> Он не заметил, когда на школьный двор забрёл большой зелёный плюшевый медведь Степан.

А почему в этом предложении вы так расставили фразовые ударения, а как вы это определили:

> Литературная и театральная критика и выступления на теоретические темы/ занимают в творчестве В. Брюсова знАчимое место,// ведь (и) всё творческое наследие поэта / воплощает в себе парадоксальное сочетание поэтического таланта / и холодного рационализма учЁного.

А почему это граница такта: ‟сочетание поэтического таланта / и холодного рационализма”, а это не граница такта: ‟литературная и театральная критика (?) и выступления на теоретические темы”?

А почему там ударение на ‟значимое”, а не на последнее слово ‟фразы” ‟место”?

**Конструктивность.**

Мои ответы и комментарии всегда отчётливы и конструктивны в отличие от ответов и комментариев некоторых людей, которые часто наполнены бредом чуть более чем полностью.

**Что в итоге.**

Термины ‟фраза” и ‟такт” лучше не использовать, так как их нужно выстроить, обсуждая разные синтаксические ситуации. А зачем выстраивать такие термины, когда можно обсудить синтаксические ситуации и сразу знаки, которые в них нужно ставить.

В итоге получилось такое определение: если есть фраза, то там в конце фразовое ударение; у этого фразового ударения нет никаких видимых характеристик – ни цвета, ни запаха, ни вида, но при этом оно просто есть, если есть фраза. Разгадка оказалась в том, что те, кто вводил эти термины, были просто умственно отсталыми и и те, кто сохранял эти термины путём их использования или включения в какие-то учебники, были тоже не самыми умными.

Comment: *Фазовое* было только ОДИН РАЗ, именно эту опечатку я и исправил, и не после, а до своего голоса.

Comment: Ладно, не буду придираться к опечатке, но мне было непонятно, потому что откуда мне знать, что там ещё нет третьего – фазового ударения.

Comment: *Он не зам**Е**тил, когда на школьный дв**О**р / забрёл большой зелёный плюшевый медведь Степ**А**н.*  В этом предложении, как я вижу и слышу, две фразы. В короткой первой фразе один такт, фразовое и тактовое ударения совпадают. Вторая фраза делится на два такта, что ощущается по произносительной паузе после слова "двор", на которое падает тактовое ударение первого такта второй фразы. Во втором такте его тактовое ударение совпадает с общим фразовым второй фразы. Как-то так...

Comment: А вот в ответе написано, что фразовое ударение только одно на фразу, а у вас два фразовых ударения на фразу – ‟двор” и ‟Степан”. Или вы смешали фразовые ударения и тактовые? Посмотрите как расставила фразовые ударения Sharon: ‟Литературная и театральная критика и выступления на теоретические темы/ занимают в творчестве В. Брюсова знАчимое место,// ведь (и) всё творческое наследие поэта / воплощает в себе парадоксальное сочетание поэтического таланта / и холодного рационализма учЁного”.

Comment: Я понял, что вы все имеете ввиду под фразовым ударением – ударение, которое никак нельзя определить по каким-либо характеристикам, но оно просто есть на конце фразы и всё. У него нет ни цвета, ни запаха, ни звука – ничего, но если есть конец фразы, то там есть фразовое ударение. Я понял вашу логику. Но иногда оно на предпоследнем слове.

Comment: Вы невнимательно прочитали. Две фразы – два фразовых ударения, на словах "заметил" и "Степан. Во второй фразе два тактовых ударения, последнее из которых совпадает с фразовым. // Оно имеет и вкус, и цвет, и запах, и звук – без этого речь будет монотонной, как у первых роботов. // Конечно, может быть и на предпоследнем слове.

Comment: Ладно, то есть это тактовые ударения. По прежнему Sharon пишет фразовые, а вы тактовые.

Comment: Нет, длинная фраза делится на такты, как в музыке. Sharon разделяет эти ударения,  я тоже.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что вы выделяете в предложении тактовые ударения, а Sharon выделяет фразовые. Я просил расставить фразовые ударения, а вы расставили тактовые.

Comment: Не понимаю, вы это специально? Прочитайте ещё раз комментарий. Там и о тактовых, и о фразовых. Sharon тоже выделяет оба этих ударения.

Comment: Проехали. Я не буду говорить больше об этом. Я понял ваши определения фразовых и тактовых ударений. Если есть фраза – там есть фразовое ударение, хотя оно никак не пахнет, не звучит, не выглядит.

Comment: То есть вы спорили о сравнительных о том, является ли тут граница такта или фразы. Чтобы такие ситуации разрешить придётся долго выстраивать эти термины, расписывать разные синтаксические ситуации. И есть много примеров, где сравнительный оборот даже не на границе такта (входит в такт), а запятая стоит: ‟Камни дробились, как стекло” (он из какого-то учебник, и я не помню из какого)? Или в таком: ‟И грусть на дне старинной раны зашевелилася, как змей (Л.)”; или в таком: ‟Низко подвешенные лампочки светились, как в тумане”; или в таком: ‟Гляжу, как безумный, на чёрную шаль (П.)”.

Comment: Да, у бреда тоже есть логика!  :))

Comment: Еще какая логика! Оказывается, запятые и все прочие знаки ставятся как раз на границах фраз, где паузы слышатся особенно четко (это грамматические паузы), Кто бы мог подумать!))

Comment: Это сложно опровергнуть, потому что это подгоняется под готовую пунктуацию, где нет точного описания, какой должна быть пауза, чтобы это была граница фразы. Но это опровергается множеством ситуаций, противоречащих этому. Например, деепричастия часто произносятся в одном такте, но имеют запятые: ‟Он вошёл, не снимая шляпу”. Те сравнительные обороты, которые я привёл. Всякие короткие предложения: ‟Он знал, что грядёт”. Всякие временные обороты без запятых. Особенно всякие обстоятельственные обороты перед сказуемым (даже очень длинные), которые почти всегда не имеют запятых, как в предложении:

Comment: ‟Из за проблем с законом я не смог устроиться на работу”. Все обстоятельственные обороты перед сказуемым имеют длинную паузу, но не обособляются. Бескрайнее количество примеров противоречащих этому. И к тому же в синтаксических ситуациях много различных пауз, и такие термины как ‟фраза”, пришлось бы тщательно выстраивать, чтобы люди не спорили о них. Проще сразу обсудить синтаксические ситуации.

Comment: Если одно однородное распространённое, то пауза длинная, но запятая не ставится. Если оба сложносочинённых предложения относятся к общему сочетанию, то запятая не ставится, а если убрать общее сочетание, то запятая будет ставиться, хотя пауза не изменится. К тому же ни в одном учебнике по пунктуации об этом не написано, что всё зависит от каких-то фраз, в справочнике Розенталя об этом ни слова. Мы всегда обсуждает конкретные синтаксические ситуации. Зависимость запятых от границ фраз – теория заговора.

Comment: Было бы очень сложно согласовать правила, если привязывать их только к паузам, а не к паузам и синтаксическим ситуациям.