# Насколько эффективен метод интонационного анализа при выборе знаков препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, интонация

Об **интонационном** анализе при постановке знаков препинания на форуме говорилось часто, но применяют  его **немногие** пользователи. Так ли он **необходим** или все же **достаточно правил** и знаний грамматики?

Можно ли оценить **эффективность**  интонационного анализа и в каких случаях его желательно использовать?

Answer (score 2):

Трудно сказать, почему интонация не так часто упоминается на форуме. Возможно, не хватает **системных знаний** по этой теме.

Без интонационного анализа очень трудно обойтись **при наличии выбора**, кода в правилах говорится о возможности **факультативного** решения задачи.

Поэтому я хочу предложить **теоретический и практический** материал, который может помочь при освоении метода.

**ИНТОНАЦИОННЫЙ ПРИНЦИП ПУНКТУАЦИИ И ИНТОНАЦИОННЫЕ МОДЕЛИ ПРИ РЕШЕНИИ ПРАКТИЧЕСКИХ ЗАДАЧ**

**1. Интонация как суперсегментная единица языка**

**[Сегментные и суперсегментные единицы](https://studopedia.su/17_87935_segmentnie-i-supersegmentnie-edinitsi-yazika-frazi-i-takti.html)**

1. В узком смысле интонация понимается как **«движение голосового тона»** и совпадает с понятием **мелодики речи.** Говорят: «вопросительная интонация», «утвердительная интонация» и др. В широком смысле термин «интонация» обозначает **сложное явление**, представляющее собой **совокупность мелодики речи**  (т.е. повышение или понижение основного тона в пределах высказывания), интенсивности, **темпа речи и пауз.** В качестве дополнительных составляющих интонации выступают **тембр речи** (при выражении иронии, сомнения, воодушевления и т.д.) и **ритм**.
2. В речевом потоке выделяются различные фонетические единицы: **сегментные и суперсегментные.** Сегментные единицы линейны, это разные отрезки речевого потока: **звук, слог, фонетическое слово, фонетическая синтагма, фраза**. Звук – наименьшая, кратчайшая сегментная единица. Каждая следующая по величине сегментная единица состоит из более мелких: слог из звуков, фонетическое слово из слогов, фонетическая синтагма из фонетических слов, фраза из фонетических синтагм.
3. Объединение этих единиц **в более крупные сегментные единицы** осуществляется благодаря **суперсегментным,** или просодическим, единицам, которые как бы **накладываются на сегментные**. К таким суперсегментным единицам относятся слоговость/неслоговость звуков, **ударение и интонация**. Особая суперсегментная единица – **темп речи**.
4. Главное их отличие от звуков в том, что они не существуют **отдельно** от материальных оболочек языковых единиц, они **характеризуют эти материальные оболочки в целом**, как бы **надстраиваются** над ними. Поэтому суперсегментные единицы не могут быть произнесены отдельно. Они, как и звуки, участвуют в различении слов, предложений.

**Сегмент** (от лат. segmentum — отрезок, полоса, от seco — режу, рассекаю) — часть чего-либо.

**2.  Несколько слов об интонации (авторское отступление)**

Интонация  **как  метаструктура!**  Невидимое нечто  представляется  особым явлением для тех, кто любит язык и  «для звуков жизни не щадит». Так переменчива эта материя! Но именно она, как божественное дыхание, оживляет нашу речь.  Это ее душа, ее сущность.

**Ударение** как магнит притягивает звуки к единому центру. И вот уже у нас не последовательность  отдельных фонетических единиц, **а само слово**!  И разве это не чудо! Но и это еще не все, потому что из слов с помощью тонического ударения создаются  более сложные структуры, а именно **фонетические фразы**.

**Тоническое ударение** заслуживает особого внимания.  На одном из слогов фразы повышается или понижается тон,  и тогда слова притягиваются к  этому интонационному  центру. Так из структур менее высокого порядка создаются структуры  большей сложности. И наконец из отдельных фраз, разделяя их паузами, мы строим **предложения**.  Все так просто, но это нужно однажды увидеть и понять. И тогда уже невозможно будет ставить знаки без учета  интонации.

А еще нашу **письменную речь**  можно представить  музыкальной пьесой, записанной на листе бумаги, где  **ноты** — знаки пунктуации.  Тональность, длительность звука,  паузы различной длины — не так уж мало, для того чтобы услышать мелодию текста.

**Интонационные модели** — это тоже интересно. Вы собираете из отдельных фраз предложения, и здесь вы архитектор и модельер.  Никогда не стоит забывать об этом. Интонационные модели нужны для того, чтобы отвлечься от сложного описания интонации и выделить в ней **существенные** признаки, которые учитываются при выборе знаков.

И прежде всего нас интересуют места **соединения фраз**, где определяется вид интонации как восходяще-нисходящая или нисходще-нисходщая. Это основной признак. А теперь добавляем **паузы** различной длительности — и интонационная **модель** готова. У каждого **знака** своя модель,  их всего-то несколько.  Остается подобрать подходящую модель для **семантики и грамматики** конкретного варианта.

**3. Правила и интонационный анализ**

Стоит ли считать интонацию **второстепенным** принципом пунктуации?  Вот уж не думаю. Все принципы важны,   они действуют **как единое целое**, но у каждого свои **особенности**. **Семантика** всегда на первом месте, но можно ли выразить  содержание, если вы не выберете  правильную форму, **грамматическую и фонетическую .**

Правила основаны **на грамматическом принципе**, и им мы пользуемся в первую очередь,  но  не это важно. **Грамматическая** форма выражается с помощью видимых   **форм** (окончаний слов, предлогов, союзов и т.д.), а **фонетическая** форма таких возможностей не имеет.

Поэтому знаки пунктуации — это **единственный способ** для обозначения такой формы. Если правила предлагают **факультативный выбор**, то его можно сделать только с помощью интонации. Интонация — это более **тонкая регуляция** для правильного обозначения формы.

**4. О методике интонационного анализа**

Таких методик может быть много, это один из способов описания речи.  Так что можно составить **собственный вариант**, но его нужно постоянно корректировать в соответствии с практикой.

За основу нужно взять **определение всех видов ударения**,  а также определение  **фразы и  синтагмы** как речевых отрезков. **Длительность** пауз также надо учитывать. **Движение тона** на стыке фраз  следует взять **из учебника**, здесь не стоит полагаться на свой слух. В частности, в учебнике Кустовой дается такое описание в теме БСП, где  интонация является **основным** средством связи.

**Любая модель** — это только приближение к реальности, она **условна** именно вследствие своей однозначности и схематичности. В действительности же в каждом предложении  приходится учитывать **конкретику варианта,**  длительность пауз и сила ударений может **меняться** в зависимости от вида синтаксической конструкции (простое или сложное предложение и т.д.).

Поэтому **практика** и постоянное наблюдение за речью — это **основа** интонационного анализа. Его нельзя в полной мере освоить **сразу**, но в конечном итоге ваши усилия будут того стоить.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

[Основы русской пунктуации](https://orfoschool.ru/page_81810/)

[Синтаксис современного русского языка](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)  (Лучше найти издания после 2013 года.) Здесь дано описание интонации в теме БСП.

Форум: [О логических, тонических и прочих ударениях при постановке знаков препинания](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474316/%D0%9E-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150163/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.